# Python get GPS location on macOS

Tags: python, macos, gps

I want get GPS Location on macOS use Native API, Is any python library can do that? Not use IP estimate location, I need is GPS location ex HTML5 Geolocation.

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a cmd that can get gps location: [WhereAmI](https://github.com/robmathers/WhereAmI)

Or [pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation/)